# Response works in Scrapy Shell, but doesn't work in code

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-shell

I'm new in Scrapy. I wrote my first spider for this site https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/?section_id=1592 and it works fine

```
import scrapy
 
class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = 'book24'
 start_urls = ['https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/']
 
  def parse(self, response):
  
     for link in response.css('div.product-card__image-holder a::attr(href)'):
       yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book)
    
     for i in range (1, 5):
       next_page = f'https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/page-{i}/'
       yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
       print(i)
      
 def parse_book(self, response):
   yield{
         'name': response.css('h1.product-detail-page__title::text').get(),
         'type': response.css('div.product-characteristic__value a::attr(title)')[2].get()
           }
```

Now I try to write a spider only for one page

```
import scrapy
 
class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = 'book'
 start_urls = ['https://book24.ru/product/transhumanism-inc-6015821/']
 

 def parse_book(self, response):
   yield{
         'name': response.css('h1.product-detail-page__title::text').get(),
         'type': response.css('div.product-characteristic__value a::attr(title)')[2].get()
           }
```

And it doesn't work, I get an empty file after this command in terminal.

```
scrapy crawl book -O book.csv
```

I don't know why.
Will be grateful for the help!

Comment: Could you pls also add the logs so we can check what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You were getting    raise

```
NotImplementedError(f'{self.__class__.__name__}.parse callback is not defined')
NotImplementedError: BookSpider.parse callback is not defined
```

according the document

> parse(): a method that will be called to handle the response
> downloaded for each of the requests made. The response parameter is an
> instance of TextResponse that holds the page content and has further
> helpful methods to handle it.
>
> The parse() method usually parses the response, extracting the scraped
> data as dicts and also finding new URLs to follow and creating new
> requests (Request) from them.

just rename your  `def parse_book(self, response): to  def parse(self, response):`
Its work fine.